# Why does is that there only has to be one $x$ needed to satisfy the equation to prove that it is a subset of the image (range)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

So, there is this question in which it needs to proven of the function the following has to be true:

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{4+9x^2}$ is $[-\frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{12}]$

(The function of domain all real numbers projected on the co-domain of all real numbers, of the given function has the restricted domain).

To approach this, each have to be a subset of each other (function and image). Therefore:

Let $y\in f(\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow$

$y = f(x) =  \frac{x}{4+9x^2} \Rightarrow$

$[-\frac{1}{12}] \leq \frac{x}{4+9x^2} \leq [-\frac{1}{12}] \Rightarrow$

Then solve. Geting how to show that:

$f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq [-\frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{12}]$

is known, however showing the reverse that:

$[-\frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{12}] \subseteq f(\mathbb{R})$

is where the problem is. To start:

Let $y\in -[\frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{12}] \Rightarrow$

$y = f(x) =  \frac{x}{4+9x^2} \Rightarrow$

$y = \frac{x}{4+9x^2} \Rightarrow$

$9yx^2+4y -x = 0 \Rightarrow$

(which is now a quadratic).

Now, it says that *at least one* $x$ needs to be satisfied to prove the subset is equal. But why? Then after you say that the discriminant of this quadratic has to be $\geq 0$ you get:

$1-144y^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow$

$(1-12y)(1+12y) \geq 0 \Rightarrow$

Now, it says since:

$-1 \leq 12y \leq 1$

That it implies:

$1-12y \geq 0$ and $1+12y \geq 0$

Now, it says, because it has a solution the restricted image is a subset of the function. It also notes after that, because this quadratic can only be true when $x \neq 0$ so then do then consider the following:

*For* $y = 0$, *take* $x = 0$ *and so,* $0\in\mathbb{R}$

But why? Thanks.

Other important points of the domain:

$-\frac{1}{12} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{12} = -1 \leq 12y \leq 1 =-\frac{1}{144} \leq y^2 \leq \frac{1}{144}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it means for $a$ to be in the image of $g$ is that we have $g(c)=a$ for some $c$. All we need is one $c$: if $g(3)=17$, then $17$ is in the image of $g$, full stop - maybe $g(5)$ also equals $17$, or maybe not, it doesn't matter.

So as soon as you've found a single $x$ such that $f(x)=y$, you know that $y$ is in the image of $f$. Now since $y$ was an arbitrary element of $[-{1\over 2},{1\over 2}]$, what you've really shown is that $[-{1\over 2},{1\over 2}]\subseteq f(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Hi, okay, but _why doesn't it matter_?

Comment: @Strikers Because that's the definition of "image." Saying "$a$ is in the image of $g$" just means - by definition - "there is some $c$ such that $g(c)=a$." It doesn't mean "there is a unique $c$ such that $g(c)=a$," or "there are several $c$ such that $g(c)=a$," or ... It just means "there is some $c$ - possibly more than one $c$, possibly not - such that $g(c)=a$." That's just the definition.

Comment: @Strikers Maybe this will help: a room is nonempty if there is some person in it. Could be only one person, could be seventeen people, doesn't matter: as soon as there is a single person in the room, it's nonempty. Similarly, $a$ is in the image of $g$ ("$g^{-1}(\{a\})$ is nonempty") if there is at least one $c$ such that $g(c)=a$ ("there is some - maybe many - $c$ in the 'room' $g^{-1}(\{a\})$").